# How to add a side borders of unseleted tabs in tabBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to give borders between UN-selected tabs i tried this but not working. Border between around live so when i switch tabs it will look grey instead of empty space

```
Container(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                        border: Border.all(color: lightGrey)),
                    child: TabBar(
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          border: Border.symmetric(
                            vertical: BorderSide(color: lightGrey),
                          )),
                      labelStyle: body14_500(Colors.white),
                      unselectedLabelStyle: body14_500(dark3),
                      indicatorColor: white,
                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                      unselectedLabelColor: dark3,
                      labelColor: Colors.white,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "Upcoming"),
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.symmetric(
                              vertical: BorderSide(color: lightGrey),
                            ),),
                            child: Tab(text: "Live")),
                        Tab(text: "Completed"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

this is how it look
[image]

Expected this
[image]

Comment: Wrapping the Container with Expanded works?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
         tabs: [
                  Tab(text: "Upcoming"),
                  Tab(
                    child:Row(
                 
                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                   
                      children: <Widget>[
                        VerticalDivider(),
                        Text("Lives"),
                        VerticalDivider(),
                      ]
                    ),
                  ),
               Tab(text: "Completed"),
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CupertinoSegmentedControl` to achieve this

```
 CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
        onValueChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectedIndex = value),
        children: cupertinoMap,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        groupValue: selectedIndex,
        selectedColor: Colors.green,
        pressedColor: Colors.green.shade100,
        unselectedColor: Colors.white,
        borderColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      ),
```

[Full code at dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9f5f0ec52212c6567d91501c941933b6&null_safety=true)

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: @Lalit Rawat  please mark it as answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I do it like this, you should be able to adjust it to match your need:

```
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
  indicator: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), color: APP_UI_COLOR_MAIN),
  tabs: tabs.map<Widget>((tab) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        border: Border.all(color: APP_UI_COLOR_MAIN, width: 1),
      ),
      child: Text(tab.label, style: TextStyle(color: tab.color, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
    );
  }).toList()
),
```